# Missing VC Redistributable using C++, SDL, CMAKE, and GitHub Actions

Tags: c++, github, cmake, sdl-2, github-actions

I have been able to get GitHub actions to compile and upload the .exe generated by the CMake file, but upon running I get a couple missing .dll files. These include: MSVCP140D.dll, VCRUNTIME140D.dll, VCRUNTIME140D_1D.dll, ucrtbased.dll. My understanding so far is that these are apart of the Visual C++ Redistributable, but I am not sure as to why it can't find these files. I am able to build the .exe using CLion and run it with no issues (have not tested on another system). Would this occur because the GitHub actions server does not have the Redistributable? How would I get around this? Has anyone been able to use GitHub actions for a SDL project?

Answer (score 0):

When linking application against Visual C++ Runtime Libraries, you can do this in two ways:

- Statically
- Dynamically

The first option allows you to embed them in an executable file. The file will be larger, and you will not need any more files to run the application.

The second option will result in a smaller executable file, but additional DLLs will be needed to run the software. Most Windows users have them installed and can share them among many applications at once.

So you can either distribute your software to these libraries or link them statically.

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I have the Visual C++ Runtime Libraries on my computer, but the exe will still give me the error. I'm not sure why this is the case. Would you know how to set up github actions to statically link these?

Comment: There is linker flag to link statically these libraries in link I sent you.